# Save expression for future use

Tags: expression-manipulation, save

I have an expression given by a summation, which takes a few hours to compile and which gives me over a million terms.

[image]

How can i save up this expression to use him another day, wihtout doing the sum all over again ?

I tried to copy and paste, buts looks like when the expression is given like the image above, copy and paste doesnt work, telling me this

`Syntax::noinfoker: This input can only be interpreted in the same kernel session that generated it.`

Comment: `DumpSave` can come in handy.

Comment: Maybe you can try the `Iconize` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Iconize` solves for me.
`Iconize[exp]`

Comment: This seems more appropriate as a comment.